# Fatal error - Call to a member function count

Tags: magento-1.9, navigation, fatal-error, toolbar

I wish to copy this content :

**app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\navigation\left.phtl**

```
<?php if (!Mage::registry('current_category')) return ?>
<?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories() ?>
<?php $_count = is_array($_categories)?count($_categories):$_categories->count(); ?>
<?php if($_count): ?>
<div class="block block-layered-nav">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Browse By') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <dl id="narrow-by-list2">
            <dt><?php echo $this->__('Category') ?></dt>
            <dd>
                <ol>
                <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                    <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?></a> (<?php echo $_category->getProductCount() ?>)
                    </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list2')</script>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In my custom toolbar :

```
app\design\frontend\mytheme\default\template\catalog\product\list\toolbar.phtml
```

But I getting fatal error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object in
>   app\design\frontend\mytheme\default\template\catalog\product\list\toolbar.phtml

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all content of template file 
`app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\navigation\left.phtml` 
inside 
`app\design\frontend\mytheme\default\template\catalog\product\list\toolbar.phtml` 
in your template use 
`echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/navigation')->setTemplate('catalog/navigation/left.phtml')->toHtml();`